# What's another way of saying "to hell with it"?

Tags: idioms, politeness, offensive-language, figurative

How do you express displeasure and disregard over something (e.g. To hell with that new policy _____'s office has come up with! I'm going to do whatever the *hell* I want) without sounding crude?

I am convinced that there are always more eloquent ways of saying something, so we all don't spiral down into vulgarities, but I can't think of a more polite way of saying it.

**To clarify:** Is there a suitable synonym for the phrase "to hell with it" that is also an idiom? Or is there another *figurative* way of saying that?

Comment: "I am unsatisfied with the new policy ____'s office has implemented and would like to demonstrate my displeasure in a most emphatic manner by performing alternative actions of my own choosing!"

Comment: You may "condemn a regrettable policy and adjust it to your style".

Comment: There must be a hundred ways to politely express disapproval. The problem is getting other people to *hear* it as 'polite'.  This isn't really about English, and there's no right answer.

Comment: ***Nuts**! I'm closevoting as POB*

Comment: @medica I hadn't thought of that. You're right, of course. Even if something is said nicely, there's always a chance someone would take it the wrong way. But what I'm looking for isn't a "right answer", but a synonym to the idiom "to hell with it" (preferably another idiom).

Comment: @John Clifford: According to Google Books, only 258 people are [*are unsatisfied with it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+unsatisfied+with+it%22) (whatever "it" might be), but about 11,600 are [*are **dissatisfied** with it.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22are+dissatisfied+with+it%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am unsatisfied with those statistics.

Comment: @John Clifford: But are you ***disinterested*** or ***uninterested***?

Comment: Although _____’s policy is an earnest attempt to solve the <xxxx> problem, it does not sufficiently address my concerns and I will therefore continue to operate without it.

Comment: I would suggest "they can forget \[about\] that!", although it strikes me that it may be a minced oath.

Comment: "I can't be doing with the new policy Head Office have come up with, I'm going to carry on regardless" or "I'll just carry on my own, sweet way" convey something of the spirited or indignant nature of the original, but as other's have said, there is no *right* answer.

Comment: [**"I never asked for this"**](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-never-asked-for-this)

Comment: Respectfully, I find myself unable to commit to complete compliance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about English, it is about how to express disagreement in the workplace that results in constructive change, without getting fired. See  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> This policy is not worth the paper it's printed on.

Uses polite language but is confrontational not diplomatic.

---

> This policy will require revision to be fully implementable.

Uses polite language, and is bureaucratically diplomatic.

---

The politest idiom for "to hell with it, I'll do what I want" I know is:

> I'll take that under advisement

Answer (score 0):

It's a little less crude to say "to heck with it," because "heck" is a euphemism for "hell."

You may also say "This new policy is for the birds."

Of course, the wisest thing to do is keep your feelings to yourself and give reasons why you believe the policy is bad.